# How to loop through all subsites under a subsite using SharePoint server object model

Tags: 2013, development, farm-solution, ssom

I want to write the following inside a c# console application:-

1. I have a site collection `http://servername/`
2. This site collection have a subsite `http://servername/customers/`
3. And inside the customers sub site I have multiple subsites such as;  `/customers/A/` , `/customers/B/` , etc.

Now I want to do the following loops:-

1. To loop through all the subsites under the `http://servername/customers/` subsite.
2. And inside each subsite (for example `/customers/A/`)
3. To get a list title = “Manager Tracking”
4. And loop through all the items under the “Manager Tracking” list?

Can anyone advice how I can perfume this using SharePoint server-side object model? The problem I am facing is that I am unable to do the following to start from the `http://servername/cusotmers/` subsite:-

```
SPWeb subsite = new SPWeb(“http://servername/cusotmers/”)
```

Where I will get this error:-

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb' does not contain a constructor that takes
>   1 arguments

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code as below:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername/"))  //site collection url
{
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("customers")) //specific subsite url
    {
        SPWebCollection subWebs = web.Webs; //get all sites under specific subsites

        foreach (SPWeb subSite in subWebs)
        {

            SPList managerList = subSite.Lists.TryGetList("Manager Tracking");

            foreach (SPListItem item in managerList.Items)
            {
                //your logic
            }

            subSite.Close();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: can you please adivce when i use lists.TryGetList("....") should i specify the list internal name or the list title ? if i need to use the list internal names ,, then can i modify this to use the list title ?

Comment: list title should be specified.

Comment: ok will check this inside my environment ,, thanks

Comment: and the tile is case insensitive is this correct? based on my test the tile is case insensitive ,,but just wanted to confirm ?

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using Site collection Object then It will traverse through all sub sites.**

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListName");

                try
                {
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.Query = "<Where>" +
                                    "<Contains>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                                    "<Value Type='Text'>" + keyWord + "</Value>" +
                                    "</Contains>" +
                                    "</Where>";

                        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                        if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
                        {
                        foreach (SPItem item in items)
                            {
                            var Title = item["Title"] != null ? item["Title"].ToString() : string.Empty;

                            }
                        }

                    }   
                }
                catch{}
        }

}
```